# Where could I find good sample papers of philosophical academic writing?

Tags: reference-request

This question deals with the methodology of academic philosophical writing.

The "paper" exercise is rather different from  "dissertation", the kind of philosophical academic writing in which I have been trained in France.

Sample papers I have come across so far are mostly historical; they deal with the position adopted by a given thinker on a given subject. For example: Plato's "On Justice" or Descartes' "On Scepticism". This was the case even in Martinich's book on the method of philosophical writing.

Is it possible to find online good papers dealing with simple questions not linked to particularly famous authors? What are some of the most prestigious journals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/) has a few millions of papers indexed by topic and relevance, a few thousands of them with preprints freely available in the sister site [PhilArchive](https://philarchive.org/).

If you are looking for exemplars of good work, I advise you to restrict yourself, initially, to work published in high quality journals such as Mind, Noûs, Philosophy and Phenomenological Research, Philosophical Review, Ethics, or Philosophy of Science, according to your interests. Any of the journals in [the PhilPapers list of most popular journals](https://philpapers.org/journals?listId=1) will do, really.

Of course, not every paper in these journals is good, and there are plenty of excellent papers published in other venues, but this is perhaps a good initial rule of thumb. In any event, the "Selected recent additions" tab on the front page of PhilArchive typically has very decent papers.

Knock yourself out!

Comment: Academia.edu is similar to Philpapers. One difference is that by joining for a yearly fee you gain access to thousands upon thousands of quality papers and can download to your own electronic library. Also, by 'following' your favorite authors you will receive email alerts whenever they post a new work. You can also email any other members and once you begin to post your own work, you will receive weekly analytics on whoever visits your website, where they live, by city and country and what they view or download. It is quite the place to be and be seen. CMS [see charlessaunders5.academia.edu

Comment: This comment contains useful information but it does read also as an advertisement and I have been asked to adjudicate. Could you revise the comment so that it gives just a reference to Academia.edu, and minimal info about the site? There is no suggestion, certainly none from me, that your comment is meant as an advertisement but it can be read that way.  I'd much rather you revised the comment than lose it altogether.